# Probability of All People being Together?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A playground has $26$ kids and $3$ different play areas. Area $1$ holds $12$ kids, area $2$ holds $10$ and area $3$ holds $4$.

If $6$ of the kids are buddies, what is the probability they get sent to area $1$?

Answer (score 1):

The total possible configurations of assignments of children to areas is given by:

\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
26\\
12,10,4
\end{array}\right)=\frac{26!}{12!10!4!}=9667357700
\end{equation}

Now, onto the total possible configurations which send the $6$ buddies to area $1$. This leaves us free room to choose out of the other $20$ kids $6$ kids to send to area $1$, $10$ to send to area $2$ and $4$ to send to area $3$, so the number is

\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
20\\
6,10,4
\end{array}\right)=\frac{20!}{6!10!4!}=38798760
\end{equation}

Hence, the probability is:

$$\frac{38798760}{9667357700}=\frac{6}{1495}\simeq 0.401\%$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability of first of those kids to be in the area 1 is 12/26, second - 11/25, and so on. The combined probability then is 12/26 * 11/25* 10/24* 9/23* 8/22*7/21 = 0.004...